# Vim plugins as root

Tags: vim

I installed [amix's vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) and [vim-php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer), which are only on the regular (non-sudo) account. If I load a file with `sudoedit filename` and try to run php-cs-fixer using `,pcd` I get the following error:

> failed to open dir: Permission denied

I also get this error if I run `,pcd` after `:w !sudo tee %`.

Running `,pcd` as sudo (`sudo vim filename`) outputs the number 4 to the file and does nothing else.

vim-php-cs-fixer shows up under `:scriptnames` for the non-sudo vim. Is there something I'm missing in order to run this plugin? Do I need to install it under the sudo vim?

Comment: Try [their issue tracker](https://github.com/stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer/issues).

Comment: If you need `sudo` to edit your files, you're doing something wrong.